# Some questions about radioactivity around 1900

Tags: physics, radiation

All the questions are closely related to each other therefore, in my opinion, it wouldn't make much sense to ask them separately. I'm trying to find the answers in historical context. I appreciate your help and time!

> It was quickly noted after the discovery of radioactivity in 1897,
> that **the total energy due to radioactive processes is about one
> million times greater than that involved in any known molecular
> change**. However, it raised the question where this energy is coming
> from. **After eliminating the idea of absorption and emission of some
> sort of Lesagian ether particles**, the existence of a huge amount of
> latent energy, stored within matter, was proposed by Ernest Rutherford
> and Frederick Soddy in 1903. Rutherford also suggested that this
> internal energy is stored within normal matter as well. He went on to
> speculate in 1904:
>
> *If it were ever found possible to control at will the rate of
> disintegration of the radio-elements, an enormous amount of energy
> could be obtained from a small quantity of matter.*

Source: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass–energy_equivalence#Radioactivity_and_nuclear_energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass%E2%80%93energy_equivalence#Radioactivity_and_nuclear_energy)

> Where does this huge amount of energy come from? For a quarter of a
> century scientists were racking their brains over this question, all
> in vain. Opinions were divided: Crookes, Pierre and Marie Curie, and
> some other scientists, were inclined to believe that radium atoms work
> as energy transformers, i.e., they at first absorb the energy of waves
> of unknown nature that permeate the entire universe, like the ether,
> and then re-emit the accumulated energy. Others likened the ejection
> of alpha particles to the process of evaporation of molecules. But
> then the particles should have different energies, and William Bragg
> in 1904 definitely established that this is not so: all the alpha
> particles coming from radium have the same energy. Rutherford insisted
> on the subatomic origin of radium's energy and was shown to be
> absolutely right by later research.

Source: [imagizer](https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img923/4051/drMaT0.jpg), [imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F863x.jpg)

Around 1900 they had already discovered alpha particles, beta particles, and gamma rays.

**Question 1:** Radium was found to be emitting alpha particles and gamma rays. Were they thinking that radium was absorbing all of these alpha particles and gamma rays from the surrounding atmosphere, and then later shooting them out as projectiles of higher energy? I think that they did know that material particles were originating from within radium and as a result radium should be losing its mass. Just like water loses its mass when some of its molecules evaporate but in radium's case the problem was that they didn't understand where all the energy for 'evaporation' was coming from and it was a huge amount of energy compared to the amount released in any known exothermic chemical reaction. Am I thinking along the right lines given the historical evolution of subject?

> The most rational explanation of this strange phenomenon is given by
> J. J. Thomson in his corpuscle theory, which assumes the existence of
> particles of matter called ions, thousands of times smaller than
> atoms. It is supposed that myriads of these corpuscles are thrown off
> at such a tremendous velocity as to generate the force which is known
> as radioactive energy. Seguin's idea, we may recall, gives
> reinforcement to the Thomsonian corpuscle theory. The incessant
> bombardment occasioned by the particles thrown off from radium may be
> demonstrated by the Crookes spinthariscope.

Source: [imagizer](https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img922/6923/9XMgjQ.jpg), [imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pP5vu.jpg)

**Question 2:** Why didn't they think that some kind of bond breaking is taking place? They could have thought that the corpuscles are held together with bonds and in some elements such as radium these bonds are unstable. Once bonds are broken, energy is released which propels the freed corpuscles outward like projectiles just like in an exothermic chemical reaction gas is released.

> The fact that certain bodies possess the power of emitting invisible
> and penetrating rays was first brought forward by Seguin. Many years
> ago it was noticed that if a coin or a print were shut up in a box in
> close proximity to a sheet of blank paper, an image was made, even in
> the absence of solar light. These mysterious functions were formerly
> accounted for as the product of superhuman agency ; but Seguin
> suggests that the bodies capable of producing this singular phenomenon
> did so by giving off a continuous stream of impalpable particles,
> projected at such a velocity as to make an impression on the substance
> which they bombarded. This hypothesis was rejected by physicists, who
> declared that such a radiation of matter going on forever without loss
> of weight was impossible. Though, indeed, almost inconceivable, yet
> this hypothesis is the best explanation so far offered to account for
> the strange behavior of the latest scientific wonder, radium.

Source: [imagizer](https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img922/6923/9XMgjQ.jpg), [imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrkNv.jpg).

**Question 3:** Who was that Seguin? Is it [Marc Seguin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marc_Seguin)? But Marc Seguin died in 1875 and radioactivity was found around 1897. Could you please help me to find more context for the mentioned Seguin's hypothesis that the bodies are capable of giving off a continuous stream of impalpable particles?

Comment: I have captured your screenshots into the SE (imgur) image site, to guard against link rot, but it is essential that you provide proper academic citations (i.e. title, author, publication venue, volume, page, year) for all your sources.

Comment: Are you asking for a recapitulation of the whole process, with all the mistakes and blind alleys, of the process of figuring it all out? It was a very messy business, and trying to read the original papers is difficult since the terminology used is pretty alien to the current lexicon.

Comment: @JonCuster Thank you. No, I'm not asking for recapitulation of the whole process. Question 1 is my own attempt, as a layperson, to understand the basic problem they were facing when it came to radioactivity around 1900, and I only need to know if my basic understanding is not way off the right track. I'm only looking for basic details in case of Question 2. Question 3 is about a person.

Comment: If you can find a copy, I really liked American 'From Nuclear Transmutation to Nuclear Fission, 1932-1939" by Per F. Dahl. While later than your primary interest, the reality is that until the early 1930’s and the start of nuclear physics, people still has no good idea of what was going on. Even lots of uncertainty (pre discovery of the neutron) what deuterium was, with one theory being a ‘nucleus’ of two protons and an electron, with a valence electron around that.

Comment: @JonCuster Thank you for the recommendation! I'd give it a look some time. I'm interested in the period between 1897 to 1905. For example, why they didn't think that it was some sort of chemical change. They knew that radium and uranium were metals, did they understand at that time that the metallic bonding was so strong that the bonds between individual metallic atoms could not be broken down. Also, why would a coin or a print when shut up in a box in close proximity to a sheet of blank paper would produce an image, even in the absence of solar light.

Comment: Well, having particles flying out with a million times the energies from normal chemistry was a pretty clear difference. It was a great unknown that clearly wasn’t what they were familiar with.

Comment: @JonCuster Agreed but it could have been some special sort of chemical bonding which they hadn't encountered earlier. The following are words of Rutherford and Soddy from 1903: *"The energy of radioactive change must therefore be at least twenty thousand times, and may be a million times, as great as the energy of any molecular change. […] the total energy of radioactive change […] can only be a portion of the internal energy of the atom, for the internal energy of the resulting products remains unknown. All these considerations point to the conclusion that the energy latent in the* **cont'd**

Comment: *atom must be enormous compared with that rendered free in ordinary chemical change. Now the radio-elements differ in no way from the other elements in their chemical and physical behaviour […] there is no reason to assume that this enormous store of energy is possessed by the radio-elements alone.*. You can see that Rutherford and Soddy made a straight conclusion that it cannot be chemical energy and said that it's latent energy of the atom itself. I need a little bit of explanation why and how they reached this direct conclusion. Thanks.

Comment: Well, they nailed it! Nuclear binding energies are way different from chemical binding energies.

Comment: @JonCuster But the only problem is that they didn't have any clear idea of nucleus back in 1903. What they said was accurate but how they came to this conclusion baffles me.

Comment: In 1901, Rutherford and Soddy studied radiation from thorium. From what they observed, they faced with the possibility of transmutation. Ever since, Rutherford had thought that the alpha particles must’ve been helium without electrons. And that was later confirmed in 1908. Since they *knew* that transmutation was occurring, they had to know that the energy scale must be much bigger than the chemical bonds. Because elements are otherwise stable!

Comment: Thank you! So, who was that Seguin?